# Does the New play billing library in android need base64EncodedPublicKey?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, play-billing-library

I'm just explore the New [Google Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html)

using google [codelabs sample](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/play-billing-codelab/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2017#0) 
, it works without base64EncodedPublicKey.

I don't no how it works without base64EncodedPublicKey, in android docs they not mention about the base64EncodedPublicKey in New Play Billing Library, can anyone explain what the advantage of using New Play Billing Library & how to works

Answer (score 0):

That key is needed to verify purchase signature on the client.
You can see the example inside [the updated TrivialDrive_v2 sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/blob/master/TrivialDrive_v2/shared-module/src/main/java/com/example/billingmodule/billing/BillingManager.java#L384).
But keep in mind, that this is not a very secure approach since your app could be decompiled.

So for security you should also introduce a backend mechanism to verify your purchases as described [here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_best_practices.html#validating-purchase-server).